# Why results of PDO are two nested arrays and how to use them

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

**Mytable:**

```
+-----+-----------+
| id  |   word    |
|-----|-----------|
|  1  |   test1   |
|  2  |   test2   |
|  3  |   test3   |
+-----+-----------+
```

**Mysql:**

```
while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo $end["word"].' - ';
}
```

output:

```
test1 - test2 - test3
```

**PDO:**

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

output: It is two nested arrays, and if I want to select one record, I should do something like this:

```
echo $result[0][word]; // output=test1
echo $result[1][word]; // output=test2
echo $result[2][word]; // output=test3
```

Now I want to know, Is there any trick to let me echo all records of a column in PDO ?

---

**Edit:**

How can I echo my data as not manually. There is manually:

```
echo $result[0][word]; // output=test1
echo $result[1][word]; // output=test2
echo $result[2][word]; // output=test3
```

So what should I do for 1000 rows ? Surely I should not do this:

```
echo $result[0][word]; // output=test1
echo $result[1][word]; // output=test2
.
.
.
echo $result[999][word]; // output=test1000
```

Any offer?

Comment: I see `mysql_fetch_assoc()` then I see `fetchAll()`. You can't use both together, `mysql_` and PDO. You must keep the same MySQL from connection to query. Or, is this a why/comparison question difference between both?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've used `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and `fetchAll()` in two different examples.

Comment: your question's unclear then. It would be best if you could edit your question for future readers, to mention the fact about "what is the difference in using both different APIs" type of thing ;-) I for one, thought you were mixing MySQL APIs. Some may also not understand the question.

Comment: Please read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php it's all in there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I read it already, I don't want the results in a array. How can I access data of record  if pdo? In fact what is equivalent of this in POD: while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){echo $end["word"];} ?

Comment: You're using `mysql_fetch_assoc` so use the same method as PDO says `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: I went over all your Q's and A's there stack... I didn't downvote anything. You got me mixed up with someone else. Unless you have another account.

Comment: If you give me the link to the deleted question, I can see it; 10k + members can see deleted questions. You can delete the link from comments after. I'm just curious as to which question that was. You've picked my curiousity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO equivalent of mysql_fetch_assoc is fetch: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

fetchAll does something like:

```
$result = array();
while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $result[] = $end;
}
print_r($result);
```

So your code in PDO will look like this:

```
while($end = $sth->fetch()) {
    echo $end["word"].' - ';
}
```

Comment: But your code will echo just `test1`, because you are using `fetch()`. I want `test1 - test2 - test3`

Comment: @stack: no, both of these examples will return all rows - the `while()` loop does this. Both of these fetches (for mysql library and for the PDO/mysql library) will read the row and move the internal pointer to the next record.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` returns **ONE** row of data, which  will be an array of fields.

`fetchAll()` returns **ALL** rows of data, so you get an array of arrays of fields.

Comment: If I use `fetch()` it returns just one result. What is equivalent of this in POD:  `while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){echo $end["word"]}`

Comment: When should I use `fetch()` ? Is it equal with `limit 1` (in sql) ?

Comment: heck no. you're using the SAME result set. you use fetch() in a loop, especially if you have to process some of the data while building your result structure. e.g. `while($row = fetch()) { do stuff with $row }`, versus calling fetchAll() which just throws the entire result set at you at once.

Answer (score 0):

The keys represent the rows(zero based) and the subarray hold the column values with column name as the key.